# How can I generate the list of number adding 5 to starting number?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, .net-4.5

This is the simple question but want to make sure that I do it right way!

I want to generate the list of numbers where I start with number 3 and add 5 to every next number.

Result should be like this:

```
var list = new List<int> { 3, 8, 13, 18, 23, 28 ..... 103 };
```

My Code:

```
var uniqueInts = new List<int>();
addBy = 5;

for (int i = 3; i < 1000; i++) 
{ 
   uniqueInts.Add(addBy); 
}
```

Am I trying correctly or there is any easy way?

Comment: That code will just add 5 to the list 9996 times

Comment: What's wrong with running the code and looking at the output? Do you have only once chance to run this?

Comment: How about `for (int i = 3; i < 10000; i+=5)` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        List<int> numList = new List<int> { 3 };

        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(numList[i]);
            numList.Add(numList[i] + 5);
        }
        Console.Read();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Increase your `for` loop index by 5 instead of 1.

```
for (int i = 3; i < 10000; i += 5) 
{ 
   uniqueInts.Add(i); 
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Just for comparison, here's a way to do it using Linq. In this case I think I prefer your loop though :)

```
var list = Enumerable.Range(0, 21).Select(x => x*5+3).ToList();
```

EDIT: Not sure what you mean by your comment below about wanting output as "var list = ...", but if you want the *string* (ie the source code) as output, you can use a Linq aggregate;

```
string str = Enumerable.Range(0, 21).
    Aggregate(new StringBuilder("var list = new List<int> {"), 
    (builder, i) => builder.Append(i*5+3 + ", ")).Append("};").ToString();
Console.WriteLine(str);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following:

```
IList<int> uniqueInts = new List<int>();

for (int i = 3; i < 10000; i+=5)
{
   uniqueInts.Add(i);
}
```

Of course you would have to define an upper limit because i < 10000 will only give you (10000 / 5) - 1 numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Change your incremental amount:

```
i += 5
```

so, applied:

```
for (var i = 3; i < 10000; i += 5){
    uniqueIds.Add(i);
}
// 3, 8, 13, 18, 23, ...
```

*Assuming that's what you meant, but your question's kind of ambiguous.*

unless you want to add 5 to every number in the list, in which case:

```
var list = new List<int> { 3, 8, 13, 18, 23, 28 ..... 103 };
var uniqueIds = new List<int>();
foreach (var n in list)
{
    uniqueIds.Add(n + 5);
}
// 8, 13, 23, 33, ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, if you want to know if you are doing it right, test it yourself in a [new console project](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0wc2kk78%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) and [debug it](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/sc65sadd%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).
Secondly,
Your code will result in a list of `{5, 5, 5, 5...}`.
What you should do is:

```
var uniqueInts = new List<int>();
addBy = 5;

for (int i = 3; i < 1000; i += addBy)
{ 
   uniqueInts.Add(i); 
}
```

This way `i` will always grow by `5` at the end of every loop and it will be added to the list..
This will give you all results between 3 and 1000 with jumps of 5, if that is what you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is wrong, it will add the number `5` every time.

Instead do this:

```
var uniqueInts = new List<int>();
addBy = 5;

for (int i = 3; i < 10000; i += 5) 
{ 
    uniqueInts.Add(i); 
}
```

Comment: I accidentally pressed submit before I was done writing the answer, my apologies.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
int num = 3;
List<int> listofnumbers = new List<int>();
listofnumbers.Add(num);
for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
{
    num += 5;
    listofnumbers.Add(num);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like perfect fit for infinite sequence with `IEnumerable<int>`:

```
IEnumerable<int> GeometricProgression(int start, int step)
{
   while(true)
   {
      yield return start;
      start += step;
   }
}
```

Usage:

```
var result = GeometricProgression(3, 5).Take(10).ToList();
```